# Add some default options in select2 when dropdown is open in remote data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 with remote data. when i click on drop-down. no option will shows until write in search box.

But i want to show some data when drop-down open.
I am trying it with `initselection` or  `data` but its initialize when data present in selected value.

```
        $('.countrySelection').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Country",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
            url: base_url+'ajax_response/getCountry',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                    page: page
                };
            },
           results: function (data, page) {
            $(".statenoSelect").select2("val", "");
            $(".citynoSelect").select2("val", "");
                 var more = (page * 2) < data.page
                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    more: more
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {
            var id = $(element).val();
            if (id !== "") {
                $.ajax(base_url+'ajax_response/getCountry?id=' + id, {
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data) { callback(data['items'][0]); });
            }else{
                $.ajax(base_url+'ajax_response/getCountry?default=true', {
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data) { callback(data['items']); });
            }
        },
        data:function(element, callback) {
            callback(JSON.parse($(element).attr('data-selection')));

        },
        formatResult: repoFormatResult, 
        formatSelection: repoFormatResult,
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    }).focus(function () { $(this).select2('open'); });
```

Its working with ajax, but how can I add options without search anything
[image: image for select2]